# Java Try-Catch confusion

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I was studying for the `OCA` exam and I found a conflicting point while  solving topics about `Java` exceptions. Here is the code causing my confusion:

```
public class StringOps {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("a");
        try {
            System.out.print("b");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.print("c");
            throw new RuntimeException("1");
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.print("d");
            throw new RuntimeException("2");
        } finally {
            System.out.print("e");
            throw new RuntimeException("3");
        }
    }
}
```

This code outputs:
 `a-> b -> c -> e`.

But I don't understand why? I thought it would output: 
 `a-> b -> c -> d -> e`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This happened because even though you threw a new `RuntimeException`, in your first catch block, this new `RuntimeException` is **still subject to the finally clause** from your first catch block.

If you wanted to ***hit multiple catches you would have to nest your try/catches***. The control flow is always:

```
 try --> catch --> finally.
```

Hopefully that helps!